# How to get all available environment-variables of docker image?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I want to get all the environment-variables available in the docker image for easy configuration at startup.

For example, when the elasticsearch image is started, the xpack.security.enabled variable can be added, etc.

```
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 --name=elasticsearch-6.5.4 -e xpack.security.enabled=false elasticsearch:6.5.4
```

How to know what other variables can be configured in this image, as shown in the help documentation?

thank you very much!

Comment: Reading documentation is the best way

Comment: Yes, you need to read the documentation. You could however exec into your container and run the `env` command to see what is already set however the returned list may/likely not be a complete view of every env var you can set.

Comment: Thanks, I know that env information can be obtained from the container instance. But I want to know if docker officially has this consideration, and add this information in the help file of the mirror. For example, docker image xxx: xxx env, of course, this needs to form a unified specification when writing a dockerfile.

Answer (score 7):

`docker image inspect {image_name}` has a section called "Env" where you can see this info.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the image, zookeeper:3.8.0.

1. you could use command `docker inspect --format '{{ .Config.Env }}' zookeeper:3.8.0 | column -t -s ' '`

```bash
[myuser@myhost zookeeper]$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea838
[myuser@myhost zookeeper]$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
zookeeper           3.8.0               d3d4daa1366e        7 days ago          279MB
```

```bash
[myuser@myhost zookeeper]$ docker inspect --format '{{ .Config.Env }}' zookeeper:3.8.0 | column -t -s ' '
[PATH=/usr/local/openjdk-11/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/apache-
zookeeper-3.8.0-bin/bin  JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/openjdk-11  LANG=C.UTF-8  
JAVA_VERSION=11.0.15  ZOO_CONF_DIR=/conf  ZOO_DATA_DIR=/data  
ZOO_DATA_LOG_DIR=/datalog  ZOO_LOG_DIR=/logs  ZOO_TICK_TIME=2000  
ZOO_INIT_LIMIT=5  ZOO_SYNC_LIMIT=2  ZOO_AUTOPURGE_PURGEINTERVAL=0  
ZOO_AUTOPURGE_SNAPRETAINCOUNT=3  ZOO_MAX_CLIENT_CNXNS=60  
ZOO_STANDALONE_ENABLED=true  ZOO_ADMINSERVER_ENABLED=true  ZOOCFGDIR=/conf]
```

`--format` [DOC](https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/)

2. And also see [commands list of zookeeper:3.8.0](https://hub.docker.com/layers/zookeeper/library/zookeeper/3.8.0/images/sha256-1425297e19cdd2323fbf2ac68aa4a92693365832a57c1e607b80dea9801e43ec?context=explore) on docker hub
3. And you should see [enviroment variables](https://hub.docker.com/_/zookeeper?tab=description) of zookeeper image on docker hub image description
4. see [Dockerfile](https://github.com/31z4/zookeeper-docker/blob/master/3.8.0/Dockerfile) on github
5. you should see the built-in enviroment of zookeeper from zookeeper doc.

---

For elasticsearch, there don't seem to be that many configuration items defined by the docker image.

```bash
[myuser@myhost zookeeper]$ docker inspect --format '{{ .Config.Env }}' elasticsearch:6.5.4
[PATH=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/us
r/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin  ELASTIC_CONTAINER=true  
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-11.0.1]
```

So, you should see the official doc of elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the image. You need to check documentation of the image.

Comment: Thanks, I know that env information can be obtained from the container instance. But I want to know if docker officially has this consideration, and add this information in the help file of the mirror. For example, docker image xxx: xxx env, of course, this needs to form a unified specification when writing a dockerfile.